# Convert list of numpy arrays into pandas series of one element

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, series

I have a pandas dataframe with a single row and a certain set of columns. I would to add a new column, with a single cell, that contains a list of K numpy arrays. I obtained a series of K array by the following fragment of code, but it doesn't do what I want.

```
pd.Series([v for v in new_column])
```

How can I do it? "new_column" is a list of K numpy arrays.

UPDATE 1: this is new_column

```
new_column = [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6]),...]
```

I would obtain the following series (pycharm debugger variables style):

```
new_column = {Series(1,)}(0,[array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6),...])
```

Comment: Can you show us the sample data and expected output

Comment: OK, I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: you first create an empty `pandas.Series` of dtype `'object'`, and then you modify the value in the first position (index 0) by using the [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) method.

```
new_column = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9])]

s = pd.Series(dtype='object')
s.at[0] = new_column

s
# 0    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
# dtype: object
```